# Como convertir un System.Object[,] en un array

Tags: vb.net

Estoy sacando de un archivo excel el valor de un rango de celdas y lo quiero meter en un array para luego ir seleccionando cada dato segun me interese el problema es que me da un error diciendome que no es posible convertir un `System.Object[,]` a un `System.Array()`.

A ver si es posible que alguien me pueda ayudar. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Dim rango As Array()
ExcApp = New Excel.Application
wBook = ExcApp.Workbooks.Open(laruta) 
wSheet = wBook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
rango = wSheet.Range("A" & TextBox3.Text & ":A" & TextBox4.Text).Value
total = TextBox4.Text - TextBox3.Text
While contador < total   
    TextBox.Text = ""
    TextBox.Text = rango.GetValue(i)
```

Comment: en vez de hacer `Dim rango As Array()`, haz `As Variant`

Comment: El problema es que luego me aparece otro error: 'System.Enum.Friend Function GetValue() As Object' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'. Me imagino que el .GetValue no tiene funcionalidad cuando declaras rango como VariantType no? Corrigeme si me equivoco, nunca me ha dado por utilizar una variable del tipo variant

Comment: prueba si no a hacer  `dim rango as wSheet.Range("A" .....)` que te hara una variable que extiende a `IEnumerable` para poder iterar

Answer (score 0):

Yo todo el tema de arrays lo defino como

```
Dim rango() as string
```

A mi es lo que siempre me funciona, aunque hay gente que también le funciona poniendo

```
Dim rango as string()
```

Y luego si necesito acceder a un dato concreto lo pongo como

```
rango(1)
```